# SVN How to see changes from first checkout?

Tags: git, svn, controls, version

I have problem at working with SVN.
I need to see what changes i made from first checkout to present status.

My steps what i have done:

1. svn co $REP/path/path
2. // edited code
3. svn commit -m "some letter"
4. // i need rewrite code
5. svn update

   // At revision 12341123.
6. ???

Now i type svn diff it shows nothing because i have commit it.

I tryed some svn diff -r 123:312321 but it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use [svn log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) command. For example:

```
 svn log -r 14:15
```